# Split a date and inserting it to a web form

Tags: java, selenium

I have a Date in string format "01-23-2004".
I want to split the date and insert every day/month/year to a different filed in a web form.

I did this:

```
public static void  dateInString()  
{
    String dt = "01-23-2004";
    String dateParts[] = dt.split("-");
    String month  = dateParts[0];
    String day  = dateParts[1];
    String year = dateParts[2];

}


public void insertBirthDateBounus() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException 
{
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayMonth,day);
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayDay, mounth);
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayYear, year);

}
```

And I received an error msg that day, mounth, year - cant be resolved by variable.

( comOps.selectDropDown is the select from drop down list to select a date. This was written in a different class with all my common methods )

Comment: Why wouldn't you? What do you think happens when you declare variables in one method and try to use them in another?

Comment: Besides variable is named `month` instead of `mounth`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this .

**1.Let `month` 、`day` and `year` as global variables**

**2.Use it in `insertBirthDateBounus` method**

```
private static String month;
private static String day;
private static String year;

public static void dateInString() {
    String dt = "01-23-2004";
    // 1.format first
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf1.parse(dt);
        String newDate= sdf2.format(date);
        System.out.println(newDate);

        // 2.split
        String[] dateParts = newDate.split("-");
        month = dateParts[0];
        day = dateParts[1];
        year = dateParts[2];
        System.out.println(month);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void insertBirthDateBounus() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayMonth, day);
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayDay, month);
    comOps.selectDropDown(birthdayYear, year);
}
```

Comment: It is ok now. No error. But the running is fail because the of the filed that should be insert is the month. In the method the month is a number and in the web from is like: Sep,Oct etc. What can i do to solve it?

Comment: Wait for moment.

Comment: You can check it .@libi

Comment: There is an error on "e" : The method e(String, String) is undefined for the type Log

Comment: Just delete it @libi

Comment: Still not insert the mouth element. what did you do to convert 01 to Jan for example?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: YES.The way  I used.

Comment: No working... how can i see that 01 becomes to "Jan"?

Comment: Code  is here ,You can `syso` to display the month .

Comment: You can check it .